# Checking if certain package option is declared inside .sty

Tags: conditionals, package-writing, package-options, xkeyval

I'm writting a package in which the user may choose between three types of documents through declared options when issuing the `\usepackage` command: `undergraduatethesis`, `technicalreport` and `academicpaper`. For this I'm using `xkeyval` so people use the command like `\usepackage[documenttype=academicpaper]{mypackage}`.

I'm organizing the package in different sections, each with a type of configuration (spacing, figure configuration, titles, etc.) and I would like to put my document-type-specific commands in these separate sections, for example:

```
\if{documenttype}{undergraduatethesis}
    % do something
\fi

\if{documenttype}{academicpaper \OR technicalreport}
    % do some other thing
\fi
```

I've tried a couple things, but I failed. The method I tried were not exactly like my situation, though.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure.  Why not? I would use boolean flags from package etoolbox.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks! I'm reading the etoolbox documentation right now, but how could I expain to LaTeX that the argument is the option I declared? \def\documenttype{}? I'll try this.

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer myself after realizing I made the mistake everyone warned me about: the placement of `\ProcessOptions`, or, in my case `\ProcessOptionsX`, since I'm using the `xkeyval` package.

I used the following bit if code to assign values to some variables in order to distinguish the three document types (for simplicity I'll call them `A`, `B` and `C`):

```
\def\A{A} % creates macro named A (not sure if this value matters)
\def\B{B} % creates macro named B
\def\C{C} % creates macro named C
```

I did that in order to later use the `\ifx` command and compare two macros. Now, using the `xkeyval` package's syntax to create package options:

```
\makeatletter
\define@key{fam}{documenttype}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{% if user types: documenttype=A
    \def\documenttype{A}}{% assigns value "A" to \documenttype macro
    \relax % not sure if needed
    }

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{% if user types: documenttype=B
    \def\documenttype{B}}{% assigns value "B" to \documenttype macro
    \relax % not sure if needed
    }

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{% if user types: documenttype=C
    \def\documenttype{C}}{% assigns value "C" to \documenttype macro
    \relax % not sure if needed
    }
}
\makeatother
\ProcessOptionsX<fam>\relax
```

Great, now the macro `\documenttype` has a value defined by the user. Now, we can write codes that will be compiled only when the user has specified a certain value to `documenttype`, using `\ifx`.

```
\ifx \documenttype \A % check if \documenttype is equal to \A
% insert commands for when user chooses A
\else % not sure if needed
\relax % not sure if needed
\fi

\ifx \documenttype \B % check if \documenttype is equal to \B
% insert commands for when user chooses B
\else % not sure if needed
\relax % not sure if needed
\fi

\ifx \documenttype \C % check if \documenttype is equal to \C
% insert commands for when user chooses C
\else % not sure if needed
\relax % not sure if needed
\fi

% exactly HERE is where I was placing \ProcessOptionsX, shame on me!!
```

That's it! Now I can use any booleans!!

Comment: Sorry, but just snippets aren't very helpful in a question, nor in most answers.

Comment: no, the `\relax` should not be needed.

Comment: What are those `\ifthenelse` statements in the key definition good for? Why not simply `\def\documenttype{#1}` (or even better `\edef\documenttype{#1}`) instead?

Comment: I would recommend to add a check for invalid user input to the key definition: `\ifx\documenttype\A \else\ifx\documenttype\B \else\ifx\documenttype\C \else \PackageError{mypackage}{invalid value for key documenttype: \documenttype}{Should be one of \A, \B\space or \C.}\fi\fi\fi`